# CiviBanking: Can we create a donor + donation in one step?

Tags: civibanking

We receive some money from donors we simply can't find in our civicrm (their account is a different name than how their are known on civi)

We would like to offer a simple step "create the donor", almost like the existing rule manual matching rule:

[image: Manual matching]

Right now, the easiest workflow we found is to open a new tab, create the contact, copy the id, add contact ID to list and select that contact.

It would save time to have a modal popup to directly create the contact. Is this already possible or is this waiting for a PR?

Is there a better workflow we missed?